# Is there a way to retrieve username when signing in to Realm Mobile Platform?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Is there a way to retrieve username when signing in to Realm Mobile Platform?

Naturally I have SyncUser.all.first which returns a SyncUser. But other than "Identity" I can't find any field that is the username.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment, [but it's been requested before](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/12), so we're considering it!

For the time being, if you want to personally identify a user, I recommend capturing that information and storing it yourself at the time of registration.